# Existing python function to loop through list and get the item with matching elements?

Tags: python

It's pretty common to have a list of dictionary and you try to retrieve the one with matching criteria, see classic example:

```
data = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'James'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Robert'}]

# to get James
for entry in data:
    if entry['id'] == 1:
        return entry
```

I am aware there is a builtin `filter` function, which can do something like:

```
james = filter(lambda element: element['id'] == 1, data)[0]
```

But it's not very tidy looking, plus if nothing is matched, it will have `IndexError`

I am thinking more like having a function with specific usage which suits 90% of the time:

```
def match_get(list, key, criteria):
   for entry in list:
        if list[key] == criteria:
            return list
```

So it looks cleaner:

```
james = match_get(data, 'id', 1)
```

Before I go ahead creating such function, I have a strong feeling there is something written already, but I cannot find it from Google, hopefully someone can tell me here.

**UPDATE:**

One thing I forgot to declare(mentioned by @Blckknght to use dictionary instead of list) is that I don't have control over the data I am reading from, eg. elastic search result.

Comment: "Before I go ahead creating such a function"... didn't you just create it?  Something like this is so simple (3 lines) that the closest you'll get to a 'built-in' method is filter or list comprehension

Comment: I meant before I go ahead creating such function in our library... having the function then I will just need one line for each use, instead of 3 lines of try catch and repetitive lambda functions...

Comment: depending on how many elements are in your arrays, you might want to look into the pandas package. For large collections, this kind of filtering is far far faster

Comment: You say: plus if nothing is matched, it will have IndexError     ...  What will happen if match_get can not find key matching the criteria?

Comment: @fukanchik it will return None, but doesn't raise exception, so you don't need to catch it to make the program to continue

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in function to do what you're asking about. However, if you use a different data structure for your data, you may be able to efficiently filter or index your data with simple code.

To start with, if you are only ever going to be searching for `id` values, and those values are unique, you could replace your list of dictionaries with a single dictionary keyed by `id`:

```
data = {1: 'James', 2: 'Robert'}
```

With this structure, finding the name that corresponds to a given `id` is a trivial dictionary indexing operation: `james = data[1]`

If you have more than one value (not just `name`), you could have the values of the dictionary be more complex objects (perhaps your original dictionaries, even).

This won't work well if you have many different keys that you'll need to search for though, nor if the values are not unique or not hashable. In that situation, you may need to use a library that can do the filtering for you.

I believe that Pandas dataframes can do what you need, though I'm not familiar enough with that system to tell you exactly how. You could also use a database system, which would probably be a good idea if your data set is very large anyway.

Comment: yes replacing the list into dictionary is a way to solve it, but in my case I read a lot of from elastic search which I don't have control over the structure.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is a very general pattern -- a linear search. I agree with blckknight above that a `dict` is most suited to what you want to do. However, there definitely are scenarios in Python where you need to do a linear search like you've described, and where we don't have controls over the source or volume. In those situations, I think Python encourages you on the one hand to eschew higher order functions -- function that takes functions, like `filter` -- in favor of comprehensions and, more specifically, generators.

Consider a generator expression:

```
 generator = (a in range(10))  # (a in range(10)) would be pointless in real code
```

A generator expression, which I believe is under the covers of most comprehensions in Python, defines a way of generating a sequence, but does not yet generate it -- and, hugely important when you're working with large data sets, does not pull the whole sequence into memory.

You can combine this with the built-in function, `next`.

```
 next(generator)  # 0
 next(generator)  # 1
```

So long as the generator is not depleted, `next` will return you the next value and advance the generator. If the generator is depleted, it will raise a `StopIterationError`, or if you've provided a default, it'll return that.

```
  next(depleted_generator, None)  # None
```

The real fun comes in when you consider all that you can do with a generator expression though. A generator expression is essentially an inline for-loop. You can use if statements to remove undesirable terms from the sequence and you can nest them (at a potential loss to legibility).

```
(i for i in range(1, 13) if i % 3 == 0)  # 3, 6, 9, 12
((a, b) for a in range(3) for b in range(3))  # (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (0, 1) ...
```

Basically, for linear searches in Python, this is what I'd recommend:

```
data = (datum for datum in source if datum["id"] == id)
desired = next(data, None)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) for such tasks.

> `itertools.takewhile(predicate, iterable)`
>
> Make an iterator that returns elements from the iterable as long as the >predicate is true.

But for this case you can customize it by replace the `break` with `continue` :

```
def takewhile(predicate, iterable):
    # takewhile(lambda x: x<5, [1,4,6,4,1]) --> 1 4
    for x in iterable:
        if predicate(x):
            yield x
        else:
            continue 

>>> data = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'James'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Robert'},{'id': 1, 'name': 'Robert'}]
>>> list(takewhile(lambda x: x['id']==1,data))
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'James'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'Robert'}]
```

And if it doesn't match any thing it return an empty list no `IndexError` :

```
>>> data = [{'id': 4, 'name': 'James'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Robert'},{'id': 4, 'name': 'Robert'}]
>>> list(takewhile(lambda x: x['id']==1,data))
[]
```

Or you can specialize it :

```
>>> def takewhile(iterable,id,val):
...       for x in iterable:
...          try:
...             if x[id]==val:
...                yield x
...          except ValueError:
...             continue
... 

>>> list(takewhile(data,'id',4))
[{'id': 4, 'name': 'James'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'Robert'}]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what the questioner is asking for at all. Your "fixed" version is `filter`, which they mention as not being what they want.

Comment: Read the question again. The `takewhile` function you've written is identical to the builtin `filter` function, and your use of it is exactly the same as the `filter` code the questioner says doesn't do what he wants.